# Not getting desired output for ArrayList elements, could any one clarify?

Tags: java

I have defined the arraylist as follows:

```
ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
```

Where Node is a class which has one character data type for storing a single character.

The output is showing some garbage value instead of printing characters:

Here is a code snippet. Can anyone explain why?

```
for(Node d : nodes){
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.println(d)` is equivalent to `System.out.println(d.toString())`

If you did'nt redefine the method `toString()` in your `Node` classe, java uses the method `toString()` of the class that your object have inherited.

By default, all classes inherited the superclass `Object` where the `toString()` method is defined as :

```
public String toString() {
      return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
   }
```

That's why it looks like "garbage"

Answer (score 2):

Your `Node` class does not override the `toString` method. That's why the default implementation is called, producing what looks like "garbage".

In your `Node` class add a `toString` method that takes no parameters and returns a `String` that describes the content of your node in an application-specific way. This will fix the output.

Comment: Okay, so I have added a toString method like the following but this works if I have String variable defined in my Node Class but I have character variable defined just like below:



class Node{
 
 char label;
 
 boolean visited = false;
 
 public Node (char l){
  
  this.label=l;
 }
 public String toString() {
        return label;
    }
    }

Comment: @Adarsh use `Character.toString(label)`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you subclass ArrayList and override the toString method, simply calling println on the ArrayList will print the address of the object reference (this is the garbage you're seeing), not the actual contents of the arraylist. To get your desired result, use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nodes.toArray());
```

BTW - the other folks are correct, you'll also need to override the toString() method of your node class (in general, it is always a best practice to override the toString() method of any class you design).

To address the problem you mentioned in your comment below:

```
public String toString(){
   return Character.toString(label);
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error in eclipse after following your code " toArray() cannot be resolved or is not a field "

Comment: toArray() is a method you call on the ArrayList. So, if your ArrayList was named al, it would be: `(Arrays.toString(al.toArray());` Make sure you've got the syntax right and let me know if you're still having trouble.

Comment: I have added the following: "System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nodes.toArray()));" Still I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Just looked at your code again and realized I had the wrong name in before. Since your ArrayList is called nodes, its `nodes.toArray();` BTW - the other folks are right too, you'll need to override the toString method of the Node class as well.

Comment: I understand that I need to override the toString() method in my Node Class just like below:

public String toString() {
        return label;
   }

However, the problem here is that the return type is a String type and in my node class I have defined label as a character variable. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Character.toString(label),  converts a character (label) to a string.